# Flutter how to show text and image in text field

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show fixed text and image on left side of text form field.

Like this

[image]

My code

```
                Container(
                  width: Width * 0.9,
                  height: Height * 0.08,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: kPrimaryColor, fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.grey, width: 1.25),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
                          fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                      hintText: "3388 3388",
                      fillColor: Colors.white70,
                      enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Its simple text field with placeholder but i am not abel to add this image and fixed label on right side

Comment: You can check it out https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `prefix` in `InputDecoration`. like this:

```
 TextFormField(
    InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon:Container(
/// Your code is here based on show your design.
    ),
  ),
),
```

I hope it's work And please let me know.

Comment: i hae added this but its only showing onfoucesd mean when i tap on textfield then icon is showing only otherwise its blank

Comment: Use prefixIcon instead of prefix . It would surely work.

Comment: @Andy I have edited my code so please you can try prefixIcon and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *prefix* property in decoration of TextFields. It allows you to provide an widget in the starting of textField. Below is an example :

```
InputDecoration(
  prefix: Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

So as in your case you could use an Row in the prefix to give both icon and a text.

Comment: i have added this but its only showing onfoucesd mean when i tap on textfield then icon is showing only otherwise its blan